# About experience or experiences and knowledge(s). Uncountable or countable?

Tags: plural-forms, singular, singular-vs-plural

How to decide use countable or uncountable form of word experience?

> Also I have required background knowledge and **experience(s)** for this
>   position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you use "knowledge" (uncountable) in the same sentence, keep the same pattern and use "experience" -- uncountable.

Also, it is advised to use the same form[s] as the prospective employer used in the job advertisement.  If they say "**experience** required: ...", you do the same.  If they use the word "**skills**", give them "skills" back.  And so on.